# MUI DesktopDatePicker Resize Calendar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I am using the DesktopDatePicker component from MUI and want to resize the size of the calendar. It's currently too big.

[image: Date Picker Calendar]

I have tried to use the styled() but I'm not sure what to put here:

```
const StyledDeskopDatePicker = styled(DesktopDatePicker)(({ theme }) => ({
'& .Mui-focusVisible': {
    height: '30%',
    width: '30%',
    backgroundColor: 'black'
}
```

}));

Here's the code for my DesktopDatePicker:

```
                    <DesktopDatePicker
                        ref={ref}
                        renderInput={(params) => <StyledTextField {...params}
                            label={label ?? ''}
                            sx={{ width: width ?? '200px' }}
                            InputLabelProps={other?.disabled ? {
                                shrink: true,
                                style: { fontSize: fontSize },
                                ...InputLabelProps
                            } : {
                                    style: { fontSize: fontSize },
                                    ...InputLabelProps
                                }}
                            size='small'
                            error={error ?? false}
                            helperText={helperText ?? null}
                            required={required}
                            onKeyPress={(ev) => {
                                if (ev.key === 'Enter') {
                                    ev.preventDefault();
                                }
                            }}
                        />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced similar issue. And even after digging up lot of documents and possible solutions, none of them worked. So I had to overwrite the calendar css classes along with element selectors like below in a separate css file. And then simply import the CSS file in the desired component.

**I believe it might not be the best solution however it does solves my issue as of now.**

```
    .MuiCalendarOrClockPicker-root,
    .MuiCalendarOrClockPicker-root > div {
      width: 290px;
    }
    
    .MuiCalendarPicker-root {
      width: 250px;
    }
    
    .MuiCalendarPicker-root > div:first-child {
      padding-left: 12px;
      padding-right: 8px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    
    .MuiCalendarPicker-root > div:first-child > div:last-child > div {
      width: 4px;
    }
    
    .PrivatePickersSlideTransition-root {
      min-height: 230px;
    }
    
    button.MuiPickersDay-root.Mui-selected {
      width: 35px;
      height: 31px;
    }
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-architecture-o1n40h) is the default codesandbox for datepicker.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-cdn-fte0zq) is the codesandbox with overwritten css datepicker.

I would be more than happy to have a better solution than the above.

Comment: This is good enough for now, thank you.

Comment: Hello, then you add className={styles.MuiCalendarPicker-root} or just import css file?

Comment: Hello @Theromantus You will have to import the css file. I've updated the answer with more elaboration. In case if you want to have look at the solution in action then please check out the code sandbox linked in answer. I hope that helps.